# Converse of Thales' theorem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I'm trying to prove the following theorem from Venema's Foundations of Geometry (2nd edition).

> **Theorem 8.3.3.** Let $\triangle ABC$ be a triangle and let $M$ be the midpoint of $\overline{AB}$. If $\angle ACB $ is a right angle, then $AM = MC$.

(This is the converse of [Thales' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27_theorem#Converse))

I know that there are different proofs of this, but I'm trying to do it according to the hint of the book, which is the following:

> **Hint:** Chose a point $C'$ on $\overrightarrow{MC}$ so that $MC' = AM$. By Theorem 8.3.1 (Thales' theorem), $\angle AC'B$ is a right angle. Use the Exterior Angle Theorem in a proof by contradiction to show that $C = C'$.

Following this hint, I get the following sketch of a proof:

1. Create point $C'$ as described to get the triangle $\triangle ABC'$. By Thales' theorem the angle $\gamma' = \angle AC'B$ is a right angle.
2. Suppose $C \neq C'$. There are two possibilities: either $C$ lays between $M$ and $C'$ ($M * C * C'$), or $C'$ lays between $M$ and $C$ ($M * C' * C$). In the following, I'm only going to look at the first case, since I guess that the second case can be handled similarly. Thus, we are in the situation shown in the figure below.

   [image]
3. Let $D$ be the point where the ray $\overrightarrow{BC}$ intersects $AC'$. Now this gives rise to a couple of triangles: $\triangle C'DB$ and $\triangle ADC$. See figure below.

   [image]
4. We have an exterior angle $\delta$ to $\triangle C'DB$, which by the Exterior Angle Theorem must be greater than the interior angle $\gamma' = 90^\circ$. However, $\angle ADC$ is a vertical pair to the angle $\delta$, so $\angle ADC$ is also be greater than $90^\circ$. But this is a contradiction since $\angle ACD$ is $90^\circ$.

**My questions**

I am not confident in this proof, because there are many unfounded assumptions I have made that I'm not able to rigorously justify. For instance:

- In order to create the point $D$, I (implicitly) used the Crossbar Theorem. However, in order to use the Crossbar Theorem, I need to know that $C$ lays in the interior of $\angle ABC'$. But how do I prove that?
- How can I be certain that $C$ lays between $B$ and $D$ (needed in order to form the triangle $\triangle DCC'$)? It's conceivable that $D$ could be between $B$ and $C$. If so, then what? If not, how to rule it out? (I am able to rule out the possibility that $C = D$).
- In the proof of the case $M * C * C'$, the [Wikpedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27_theorem#Alternate_proof_of_the_converse_using_geometry) simply states that the angle $\angle AC'B$ must be acute. But how do you prove that? (Beware that this page uses different labels for the vertices than what I did here).

**Note**

Again, I know that there are other ways of proving this theorem. But I am *not* interested in those.

Comment: Do you know the sum of the angles in a triangle?

Comment: @Thomas The question is tagged with euclidean-geometry; so yes, this is known (in fact I used that in Step 4). However, I'm not sure I understand what you intend to say with your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could avoid introducing point $D$ altogether. By the Exterior Angle Theorem you have 
$$
\angle BCM\ >\ \angle BC'M
\quad\hbox{and}\quad
\angle ACM\ >\ \angle AC'M.
$$
We then get
$$
\angle BCM+\angle ACM\,>\,\angle BC'M+\angle AC'M,
\quad\hbox{that is}\quad
\angle ACB\,>\,\angle AC'B.
$$
But that is a contradiction.

Comment: Ah, of course! This is so obvious...in hindsight of course. Thanks!